# How to check if count is 1 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a `Select` query with a  `where` condition and in that condition I have to check if I am getting only 1 record. I have tried this query shown below, but it didn't work out.

```
SELECT *
FROM wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM
         (SELECT TOP 1 WCS.ExpiryDate
          FROM wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation AS WCS
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[wsm_Ref_State] AS ST ON WCS.StateID = ST.StateID
          WHERE WCS.CertificationID = 22653
            AND ExpiryDate >= GETDATE()
          ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC) AS A = 1);
```

Comment: Your expected output is not very clear. What kind of output you want if it is 1 result and when it's not?

Comment: basically the select statement count in where clause should be Equal to 1

Comment: So you want to return whole table if your inner query is equals to 1?

Comment: yes @EvaldasBuinauskas

Answer (score 2):

Since you are selecting `TOP 1`, then checking to see if the count is one, I am pretty sure that you can just replace your logic with [`EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation AS WCS 
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[wsm_Ref_State] AS ST
                         ON WCS.StateID = ST.StateID
             WHERE  WCS.CertificationID = 22653 
             AND    ExpiryDate >= GETDATE()
        );
```

Comment: will this not check it exists? not that there is only 1 row? it could be there multiple times

Comment: @dbajtr Yes, but the query in the question uses `TOP 1` before the count, so the count would return 1, even if there was more than one matching record in the whole set. All I have done is simplify the logic to remove the sort and the count, to just use exists, which should optimise better.

Comment: true didnt see that. I agree exists would be the most performant

Answer (score 0):

your query has a syntax error. you can also ignore order by clause in inner query

```
SELECT *
FROM wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation
WHERE(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WCS.ExpiryDate
    FROM wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation AS WCS
         INNER JOIN [dbo].[wsm_Ref_State] AS ST ON WCS.StateID = ST.StateID
    WHERE WCS.CertificationID = 22653
          AND ExpiryDate >= GETDATE()
    ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC
) AS A) = 1
```

Comment: Isn't count always going to be one because you're selecting `TOP(1)`?

Comment: Yes. the requirement is to check if a record exists.

Comment: i need Order by  as i want to get the biggest date

Comment: If this query has not worked for you, then please edit your question to clarify your requirement.

Comment: @AkhilJain If you aren't selecting the record, just checking if it exists, why does it matter if it is the most recent date, or the earliest date?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correct. That's probably the query you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation
WHERE EXISTS (   SELECT TOP 1 1
                 FROM wsm_Certification_WorkersCompensation AS WCS
                 INNER JOIN dbo.wsm_Ref_State AS ST
                     ON WCS.StateID = ST.StateID
                 WHERE WCS.CertificationID = 22653
                 AND ExpiryDate >= GETDATE()
                 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1);
```

`HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` will check whether the count of matches in your inner query is 1 and if not will not return anything.